# Thinning of (mixed) binomial point process

Tags: pr.probability, stochastic-processes, laplace-transform, levy-processes

Let $N= \sum_{i=1}^M \delta_{X_i}$ be a mixed Binomial process over $(\mathbb X, \mathcal X)$. I.e., $M$ is a $\mathbb Z_+$ valued random variable with probability mass function $q_M(m)$, $m=0, 1, \ldots$ and $X_i \sim P$ (i.i.d).

Consider a kernel $p: \mathbb X \mapsto [0, 1]$ and let $N_p$ be a $p$-thinning of $N$: each point $X_i$ in $N$ is retained with probability $p(X_i)$.

What is known about $N_p$?

Straightforward calculation show that the Laplace functional of $N_p$ is
$$
\mathcal L_{N_p}(f) = \mathbb E\left[- \int f(x) N_p(d x)\right] = \mathcal L_N(\tilde f)
$$
where $\tilde f(x) = - \log\left(p(x) e^{- f(x)} + 1 - p(x) \right )$. Moreover,
$$
\mathcal L_N(g) = \mathbb E_M \left[\left\{ \int e^{-g(x)} P(dx)\right\}^M\right]
$$

When $M \sim \mbox{Poisson}(\lambda)$ then $N$ is a Poisson process and $N_p$ is again a Poisson process with modified intensity.
My intuition is that $N_p$ should be a mixed binomial process as well given the similarity with Poisson processes, but I cannot prove/disprove it.

Comment: In your definition of a mixed binomial process, must $M$ be independent of the $X_i$'s?

Comment: I always thought that was the case!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\newcommand{\XXX}{\mathbb X}\newcommand{\de}{\delta}$The answer is yes.

Indeed, for any nonnegative measurable function $f$ defined on $\XXX$, letting $Nf:=\int f\,dN=\sum_{i=1}^M f(X_i)$ and assuming that $M$ is independent of the $X_i$'s, we have
\begin{equation*}
    Ee^{-Nf}=\sum_{m\ge0}q_m(Ee^{-f(X)})^m, \tag{1}\label{1}
\end{equation*}
where $X:=X_1$ and $q_m:=P(M=m)$.
Next, we may write
\begin{equation*}
    N_p=\sum_{i=1}^M \de_{X_i}\,1(U_i<p(X_i)),
\end{equation*}
where the $U_i$'s are independent random variables (r.v.'s) uniformly distributed on $[0,1]$ and independent of the $X_i$'s and $M$.
So, letting $U:=U_1$, we have
\begin{equation*}
    Ee^{-N_pf}=\sum_{m\ge0}q_m(Ee^{-f(X)1(U<p(X))})^m.
\end{equation*}
Next,
\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}
    &Ee^{-f(X)1(U<p(X))} \\
    &=\int P(X\in dx)\int_0^{p(x)}du\,e^{-f(x)}+\int P(X\in dx)\int_{p(x)}^1 du \\ 
    &=\int P(X\in dx)[p(x)e^{-f(x)}+1-p(x)] \\  
    &=1+\int P(X\in dx)p(x)(e^{-f(x)}-1).   
\end{aligned}
\end{equation*}
Introducing now a random element $Z$ in $\XXX$ with the distribution
\begin{equation*}
    P(Z\in dx)=\frac{P(X\in dx)p(x)}c,\quad\text{with}\quad c:=\int P(X\in dy)p(y)\in(0,1] 
\end{equation*}
(and avoiding the trivial case with $c=0$), we get
\begin{equation*}
    Ee^{-f(X)1(U<p(X))}=1+c\int P(Z\in dx)(e^{-f(x)}-1) \\ 
    =cEe^{-f(Z)}+1-c. 
\end{equation*}
So,
\begin{equation*}
    (Ee^{-f(X)1(U<p(X))})^m=\sum_{j=0}^m\binom mj c^j(1-c)^{m-j}(Ee^{-f(Z)})^j
\end{equation*}
and hence
\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}
    Ee^{-N_pf}&=\sum_{m\ge0}q_m(Ee^{-f(X)1(U<p(X))})^m \\ 
    &=\sum_{m\ge0}q_m \sum_{j=0}^m\binom mj c^j(1-c)^{m-j}(Ee^{-f(Z)})^j \\ 
    &=\sum_{j\ge0}r_j(Ee^{-f(Z)})^j, 
\end{aligned}
\end{equation*}
where $r_j:=\sum_{m=j}^\infty q_m\binom mj c^j(1-c)^{m-j}$.
So,
\begin{equation*}
    Ee^{-N_pf}=\sum_{j\ge0}r_j(Ee^{-f(Z)})^j. \tag{2}\label{2}
\end{equation*}
Choosing $f=0$ in \eqref{2}, we see that $\sum_{j\ge0}r_j=1$.

Finally, comparing \eqref{2} with \eqref{1}, we conclude that any "thinned" mixed binomial process is indeed a "nonthinned" mixed binomial process: $N_p$
is equal in distribution to the random measure
\begin{equation}
\tilde N_p:=\sum_{i=1}^J \de_{Z_i},     
\end{equation}
where the $Z_i$'s are independent copies of $Z$ and $J$ is a r.v. independent of the $Z_i$'s and such that $P(J=j)=r_j$ for all $j$. $\quad\Box$

---

The probabilistic meaning of the random measure $\tilde N_p$ is transparent: Refer to $X_i$ as the random position of the $i$th particle in the space $\XXX$. Then, for each $i$, the r.v. $p(X_i)$ is the conditional probability that the $i$th particle will survive (be retained) given its position $X_i$. So, $c=\int P(X\in dy)p(y)=Ep(X_i)$ is, for each $i$, the "total", space-averaged survival probability of the $i$th particle. So, the distribution of each of the independent $Z_i$'s is the conditional distribution of the position $X_i$ of the $i$th particle given its survival. Finally, the conditional distribution of the random time extent $J$ given the random time extent $M$ is the binomial distribution of the number of successes in $M$ independent trials with success probability $c$ in each trial, if success is defined as survival.